# mousedown=click. What about release?

Tags: jquery

When I click (without release the button) I can use `mousedown()` :

```
$('.myClass').mousedown(function (e) {

});
```

But what can I use when I release the button? `mouserelease()` doesnt exist :)

Comment: (just a joke for coffee time) :) if `mouseleft` existed... you'd use `mouseeast` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [`mouseup`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) event:

```
$(".myClass").mouseup(function(e) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [this one](http://jsbin.com/oyinaj/1/edit):

```
$(".myClass").on('mousedown mouseup',function( e ){
    if(e.type == 'mousedown'){
         // Do my stuff on mousedown
    }else{
         // Do my stuff on mouseup
    }
});
```